# ValueError in MySQL python sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to search a specific column in a MySQL database for lines that contain strings, e.g. if the strings I am searching for are ['bar', 'foo', 'dog', 'cat'], and the column has sentences, e.g. 'This is a sentence' I want to pick out all the database rows in which there is a matching string in the sentence. So if 'This is a cat' were in the column I am searching though, this should be returned.

To do this I am making a query using sqlalchemy like:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sql

connect_string = 'some_db_address'
sql_engine = sql.create_engine(connect_string)


query = """SELECT * FROM database
           WHERE column_name LIKE '%word1%'
           AND column_name LIKE '%word2%' """

result = pd.read_sql_query(query, sql_engine)
```

This is giving me a `ValueError: unsupported format character 'L' (0x4c) at index 87` error- any ideas why this is arising?

edit:

I am using a python fstring to make the query, like:

```
query = f"""SELECT * FROM database
                 WHERE column_name LIKE '%{word1}%'
                 AND column_name LIKE '%{word2}%' """
result = pd.read_sql_query(query, sql_engine)
```

Where the number of word variables changes, but in the above raised example word1 began with 'L', hence the error message

Comment: What is pd? Could you share more context and stacktrace?

Comment: Add more code, including what word1 and word2 are formatted to be.

Comment: It's hard to believe that the code presented here would cause that error, because there is no `%L` anywhere. The error is the result of internal details of your MySQL driver, which uses %-formatting internally, after escaping any parameters. Are you using some form of string formatting in your actual code to substitute word1 & word2? If so, there's your problem; you should never pass arguments to queries that way, but use your driver's placeholders instead and pass the arguments to execute separately.

Comment: @lija I've updated the question, I was using python f strings, not sure why that would make a difference though?

Comment: @merrydeath pd is pandas

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 word1 began with 'L' in the particular example in which I reproduced this error, generally though the words are not anything complex, just made up of letters like 'dog' etc rather than '@_Dog%' or anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to confirm that your approach fails with both mysqlclient and PyMySQL. There is definitely something peculiar going on with `read_sql_query` when the SQL command text contains percent signs.

However, as noted in the comments, using SQL injection like that is a "Bad Idea"™ anyway. Instead, you should be using query parameters like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:toot@192.168.0.179:3307/mydb")

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 (txt varchar(50))"))
    conn.execute(
        sa.text("INSERT INTO tmp1 (txt) VALUES ('Apple Lemon'), ('Lemon')")
    )

word1 = "Lemon"
word2 = "Apple"

qry = sa.text("SELECT * FROM tmp1 WHERE txt LIKE :p1 AND txt LIKE :p2")
my_params = {"p1": f"%{word1}%", "p2": f"%{word2}%"}
result = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine, params=my_params)

print(result)
"""console output:
           txt
0  Apple Lemon
"""
```